# How can I print a list of AWS instances with: 1) Instance name 2) Instance size 3) aws:cloudformation:stack-name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I currently have below AWS CLI command:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/aws  ec2 describe-instances --profile test --region eu-central-1 --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceType,Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[],Tags[?Key==`DomainName`].Value[]]' --output text
```

This returns:

- nat.mgmt.
- mgmt.
- t2.micro

But I'd like to see it printed on the same line split by tabs or commas.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to see everything in one line split by commas, you can write something like this:

```
 /usr/local/bin/aws ec2 describe-instances --region eu-central-1 --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceType,Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[],Tags[?Key==`DomainName`].Value[]]' --output text | paste -sd "," -
```

Same with tabs:

```
 /usr/local/bin/aws ec2 describe-instances --region eu-central-1 --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceType,Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[],Tags[?Key==`DomainName`].Value[]]' --output text | paste -sd "\t" -
```

So, the answer is to use bash [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) and [paste](https://ss64.com/bash/paste.html)

Answer (score 0):

you might have multiple instances returned and you could use `awk` to merge lines into one.

In you case, 3 values retuned for one instance, so we could merge 3 lines into 1

comma delimiter, add

```
| awk '{line=line "," $0} NR%3==0{print substr(line,2); line=""}'
```

tab delimiter, add

```
| awk '{line=line "\t" $0} NR%3==0{print substr(line,2); line=""}'
```

so that you have the information for one instance in each line. if you want to extract more information, you can change the `3` in `NR%3` to the number of information you want to extract